# Two versions of ruby installed

Tags: command-line, homebrew, ruby

It seems like I have two versions of ruby installed. (3.3.0 and 2.6.10.210)

How to fix that?

```
peter@mac ios % sudo gem update --system
Password:
Updating rubygems-update
Fetching rubygems-update-3.5.6.gem
ERROR:  Error installing rubygems-update:
    There are no versions of rubygems-update (= 3.5.6) compatible with your Ruby & RubyGems
    rubygems-update requires Ruby version >= 3.0.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210.
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `version' for nil:NilClass
peter@mac ios % brew install ruby
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
################################################################################################################################################################################################################################# 100.0%
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
################################################################################################################################################################################################################################# 100.0%
Warning: ruby 3.3.0 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 3.3.0, run:
  brew reinstall ruby
peter@mac ios % brew install rubygems-update
Warning: No available formula with the name "rubygems-update".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae and casks...
Error: No formulae or casks found for rubygems-update.
peter@mac ios % brew install rubygems       
Warning: No available formula with the name "rubygems". Did you mean rubyfmt?
macOS provides gem as part of Ruby. To install a newer version:
  brew install ruby
peter@mac ios % brew upgrade ruby
Warning: ruby 3.3.0 already installed
peter@mac ios %
```

Comment: macOS comes with ruby 2.6.10.

Comment: @benwiggy Ok, 2.6.10 is the preinstalled, can I uninstall the 2.6.10 to use only 3.3.0?

Comment: No. It's part of the OS.

Comment: @benwiggy Ah, Ok, no macos without Ruby in a specific version, Ruby is the core macos. So how to tell gem to use ruby3.3.0 instead of ruby2.6.10.210?

Comment: Anyway, I try to upgrade the OS from Ventura 13.6.1 to Sonoma 14.3.1.

Comment: I do not know what happened. I executed `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash` and rvm installed. Rvm is required in order to manage Ruby versions.